# Angular 2\4 hash url keep index.html

Tags: angular

Background: Angular 4, ng cli, RouterModule, useHash: true.

when I browse to my app using `http://server/index.html` it resolves to `http://server/#/` (index.html is omitted from the url) additionally every routing navigation also omits the index.html from the url.

This is problematic for how my app is hosted, I need to keep index.html in the url. How can I configure angular to keep it?

Comment: why would this be a problem for your server?  if no document is specifically requested, `index.html` should be the default for the server?

Comment: unfortunately that's not the case with the server I'm using, it requires resources to explicitly be requested (index.html)

Comment: that's a very non-standard server;  It doesn't seem like it will work with Angular (or any modern SPA framework).  What server is this, exactly?

Comment: not technically a server, I'm using Azure Storage (S3 equivalent) for static file serving which currently requires resources to be explicitly requested: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6417741-static-website-hosting-in-azure-blob-storage

Comment: why are you trying to use Azure *Storage* as a web host?  There are other Azure services designed specifically for this task.....

Comment: It's the most cost effective, and BTW it's a common pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/static-content-hosting , just happens to be the implementation on Azure Storage is lacking this feature. Not by chance this is #2 most voted issue. If I did the same on S3 I don't think it would raise any eyebrows

Comment: We are digressing. I think that it's a legitimate ask to keep to the http / url specs, and if Angular can't do that - that's an answer as well. I just want to be sure.

Comment: well honestly that's the answer.  Angular is a *dynamic* framework, and you have listed documentation regarding usage of a storage service for hosting *static* content.  This isn't an angular issue. period.

Comment: Why not take a look at [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) for your hosting solution? You're using Azure Storage, and as other said it's supposed to be for content hosting, not serving your web application. Azure could be great for your assets, or the JS bundle files, but not for serving the `index.html` as the primary page for all web routes.

Comment: @Claies That's an interesting point. I am considering Angular as a SPA framework meaning it is *static* bunch of files on the server that comes to life only on the client. Therefore I expect Angular to be *dynamic* on the client, not on the server. If it has any assumptions about the server it is not a SPA... won't you agree?

Comment: no, I don't agree.  Angular uses a variety of features like AJAX Asynchronous HTTP to deliver partial content.  It is **very likely** that even if you were able to correct your routing issues, you would have issues with other assets.

Answer (score 8):

You can try:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /app/index.html
```

but it might affect relative path to your assets.

Comment: Can also add it to angular-cli.json. This helped me on building my chrome extension using angular 2+. The extension got lost if I didn't had the index.html as a base path.

Comment: you can also set the base href value in the index.html file

Answer (score 0):

`index.html` is not a known route by the Angular router. Once it is loaded into memory it redirects unknowns to the default route which is usually `'\'` and wipes out the `index.html` and any additional path or query parameters.

Something like this should do the trick ...

```
[
    { path: 'index.html', component: AppComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'index.html', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'index.html', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

Also answered here: [How to preserve index.html and query params in URL in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56648394/how-to-preserve-index-html-and-query-params-in-url-in-angular-6/75213255#75213255)