# How to preserve index.html and query params in URL in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I need to preserve the index.html and query params in URL as it is. But when default route is loaded, they are removed and the default route is added with '#'. Is there any way to keep index and query params permenantly on URL.

Comment: Can you explain the scenario in detail

Comment: Let's assume I use "http://localhost:4200/index.html?name=max&id=085" . My default route is 'session'. When I launch the application, URL is updated to "http://localhost:4200/#/session". But I want to preserve it like  "http://localhost:4200/index.html?name=max&id=085#session". Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This may be useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985572/how-to-define-default-route-with-parameters-in-angular-component-router

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2\4 hash url keep index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44615646/angular-2-4-hash-url-keep-index-html)

Answer (score 0):

Update the base tag to something like:

```
<base href="./index.html" />
```